# How to share QR code on react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code

I'm creating an app to generate a QR code, and then share it on social media. Currently, I manage to create the QR code, however, I'm lost at sharing the generated code as an image. I'm using snack expo to build the application. May somebody show me at which part did I do wrong for the shareQR function? Thanks for your help.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert, View, Share} from 'react-native';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

export default function App() {
  const shareQr =()  =>{
    QRCode.svg.toDataURL((link) => {
      const shareImageBase64 = {
        title: "QR",
        message: "It's a QR code",
        url: `data:image/png;base64,${link}`
      };
      Share.open(shareImageBase64);
    })};

  const [qr, setQr] = useState(false);
  const [link, setLink] = useState('');

  const createQr = () => {
    if (link) {
      setQr(true);

    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        "Please insert required field"
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Create QR Code</Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="Insert link here.."
              onChangeText={(link) => setLink(link)}
            />
          </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => createQr()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Create</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {qr && (
          <View style={styles.qrcontainer}>
              <QRCode value={link} size={250} />
              <Text
                style={{
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                  fontSize: 15
                }}>
                {link}
              </Text>
          </View>
        )}
        {qr && (
          <View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => shareQr()}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Share QR Code</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'black',
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 5,
    flex:1
  },
  buttonTitle:{
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'lightyellow',
    marginVertical: 5
  },
  qrcontainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

The code above can be used directly on snack's app.js for testing. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the `base64` image url for the `QRCode` generated? If you are getting that successfully then there's a way to share that Image

Comment: the qrcode module should have already able to provide the base64 url, in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You should use "npm i rn-qr-generator". Enable base64 string then share

```
RNQRGenerator.generate({
                value: response.link,
                height: 140,
                width: 140,
                base64: true
            })
                .then(response => {
                    const { uri, width, height, base64 } = response;
                    console.log("64" + base64)
                    setQrImage(uri)
                    setQrImageData(base64)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log('Cannot create QR code', error));

const shareImageBase64 = {
        title: "QR",
        message: "It's a QR code",
        url: `data:image/png;base64,${StrinBase64}`
      };
      Share.open(shareImageBase64);
```